# WordPress - Roaming User Profiles functionality?

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

Our company is currently updating its intranet and is a multi-national company. The update for the intranet is being developed using WordPress. We have been given a requirement with regards to a users profile being able to roam based on what country they are in and to this point we are not sure whether or not WordPress can provide this functionality or if there is a plugin available and would like some help.

**Here is an explanation of our requirement/problem:**

When a user logs in to the Altranet (intranet) their location code is determined by their Active Directory (AD) Group. This code is required to provide access to country specific documents/messages/items on the altranet eg: the employee handbook for UK staff should only visible to UK based staff as defined in the AD Group.

Many staff travel globally so these specific staff need to have a default location code, plus have the ability to switch to another location if required. The new location will then determine what documents/messages/items they can access. So for example, a member of staff based in UK who can also roam to US should be able to see the UK staff handbook only, but if they switch location they need to be able to see the US handbook only.

To allow this to happen the user will need to be allocated a specific number of location codes and not just a default location. Also, the documents etc will need to be tagged per location also – I believe messages can already be tagged.

We do not want users having more than 1 username but we do need a solution within Wordpress to allow for this functionality.

**Summary:**

Would anyone be able to offer any advice as to whether this can be achieved in WordPress or know of a particular plugin that would allow a developer to fulfill this requirement? 
Can you write code in WordPress to develop this functionality?

Any more information needed let me know!

Answer (score 0):

Why not get the AD code and apply it to the User Meta then add a new Meta value for roaming based on the AD code in the 'travelled to' location.

The following should help you with this: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_user_meta/

Then you could add the following into a plugin or the functions.php file

```
    $location_code = US;
    $roaming_code = GB;
    // Consider an array for other locaitons such as $other_permitted = array("NL", "FR", "SP");
    add_user_meta( $user_id, '_location_code', $location_code);
    add_user_meta( $user_id, '_roaming_code', $roaming_code);
```

Prior to that you would need to determine the roaming code somehow from the Altranet but that is beyond the scope of this.

Comment: You could also use custom roles using 'add_role' and wrap functions using: 'current_user_can' to determine whether they have permission to access those documents. See: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_role/ and https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/current_user_can/ for more info.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! @TomC , We are going to take a look at your suggestions and will let you know how we get on :)

Comment: How did you get on?